# Starting script/console for Ruby on Rails with Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I'm having trouble starting script/console.

I've tried `cd`'ing into the project root ("C:\MyProject") then typing "script/console" and I get this:

'script' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

And when I type "ruby script/console" I get this:

Ruby: No such file or directory -- script/console (LoadError)

Any ideas?  Should I be running these commands from the root?  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usage `ruby script/console` is present in Rails 2.3.x versions and older. I believe you installed Rails 3.x which deprecated that command.

You need to use now `rails console` or `rails c` (short version) from the application directory.

Better pay a visit to the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) for all the other changes.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you need to use backslash (\) instead of the regular slash (/).

`script\console` should work for you, provided you use Rails 2.x. On Rails 3 use `rails console` as mentioned by other coleagues.

Comment: actually forward slashes will work on Windows, but that is because Ruby handles them specially.

Answer (score -1):

Is ruby installed? Is it in your PATH?

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

When it installs, look for the checkbox to add ruby to your path.

If it's already installed, then (on Windows 7), go to the Start Orb, type "path" and click on "Edit the system environment variables". Click on "Environment Variables". In the bottom list scroll down to "Path". Select "Path" and click "Edit". At the end of the "variable value" list put another semi-colon and the path to your ruby.exe.

EG: ";C:\Ruby\bin"

DO NOT delete anything else from that field.

Comment: Ruby is installed fine, it obviously found the ruby exe if you look at the error message, which is generated by Ruby.